# How to check Windows version in CMake?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, cmake

How do I check with CMake whether I'm configuring a Visual Studio solution for e.g. Windows 7 or Windows 8?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can use `execute_process` and execute `ver` to get the verion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION`

```
## Check for Windows ##
if( WIN32 ) # true if windows (32 and 64 bit)

    ## Check for Version ##
    if( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION} EQUAL 6.1 ) # Windows 7
        # Do something here
    elseif( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION} EQUAL 6.2 ) # Windows 8
        # Do something here
    else() # Some other Windows
        # Do something here
    endif()

endif()
```

Comment: Won't this give the version cmake is running on instead of the target system?

Comment: No, it returns the version of the system you're compiling for. I guess what you means is `CMAKE_VERSION` - this variable specifies the version of the cmake executable.